# Internet Download Manager for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, wine, idm

How to install IDM for Ubuntu 16.04 integrated with Google chrome?

Answer (score 1):

IDM is windows based download manage and it does not offer for Linux.

You may try one of below alternative:
1. uGet
2. SteadyFlow
3. FlareGet
4. kGet
5. XDM(Xtreme Download Manager)

Please refer this url : http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/5-best-linux-download-managers